# Changing a UITableView size in storyboard

Tags: objective-c

When i drag a `UITableView` to my `storyboard`, i need to change its size, to add a few buttons and a `search bar` above it .
There is no option in `storyboard` to stretch/change the size of that table.

How would you do that ?

Can it be done using `storyboard`, or programatically ?

Comment: Are you using UITableViewController or UIViewController?

Comment: using the first. thats because if i put a uiviewcontroller on storyboard and than try to drag and drop a tableview into it, i can't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add the UITableView on the UIViewController's view instead of replacing it, you should be able to change it in the Size Inspector after selecting the table view.

It's 100% possible, as I have a tableview with a rect of 0,175,320,280.

Edit: To add a UITableView onto a UIViewController, select the VCs view, then drag a UITableView onto it (make sure you don't replace the view instead of adding it as a subview).

Comment: You can't drag a uitableview to an existing view controller- it wouldn't let you. you have to create a tableview controller= drag the table to the storyboard, and than you can't change its size

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to drag a UITableView on to an existing UIViewController? :|

Comment: if i am trying to drag a uitableview to a view controller it wouldn't let me. i have to drag a tableview to the storyboard and not to a specific view controller… :(